# Stop disingenuine CloudKit calls?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, ckquery

I have a CloudKit app that has data in publicDB. This is secure data that's able to be created and read by any authorized user, but I limit that based on the querys my app makes. For example, a data object stating a relationship to user A and user B, but not user C won't ever be queried by user C.

I'm concerned about the possibility of somebody potentially jailbreaking/hijacking my app and performing queries which an authorised app has the ability to do, but wouldn't ever do. How can I be sure that an 'Authenticated' user is in fact a genuine authenticated user using my app normally, and not some third party injecting code into my app?

Comment: I have the same doubt because now you can create a token for WEB/JS access and anyone can change something. What I do in a testing idea is use encryption when the data is private and other users should not have access to read it. Is very complicated, but is a solution when your data is sensitive and must be in the publicDB. Try asking directly to apple in the bug reporter.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit which domains are allowed to make queries against your CloudKit container. In the CloudKit Dashboard, click on your container, then go to **API Access**, click on your API token, then note the domain restriction option:

[image]

As long as you set it to your own domain name, you'll be fine.